# PHP login verification won't work with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When this code runs it returns an error message saying that the login has failed.
The specific error message is in the else statement when the password_verify function does not run and returns the following error message with the var_dump function. It seems like the problem is with the prepared statements as the login variables being entered don't seem to be collecting the information from the database.

> Login Failed: (0)array(0) { }

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'myTable');

if ($mysqli->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
}
ob_start();
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['LogIn'])) {
    $username = $_POST['userName'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Username, Password FROM user WHERE Username = ?"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->bind_param('s', $username)) {
        echo "Bind failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
    }

    $userdata = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $userdata->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
    $stmt->store_result();

    if (password_verify($password, $row['Password'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['UserID'];
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        //  header('Location: Account.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Login Failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
        echo "Password's do not match";
        var_dump($_SESSION);
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Try converting this line: `$stmt->bind_param('s', $UN);` to `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $UN, $UN);`. Because there are 2 placeholders used.

Comment: I have tried it but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Don't let people login through usernames, if you do a malicious actor is already 50% of the way to accessing the account!

Comment: error checking should be throwing you something like "number of binds do not match..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for.

```
if(isset($_POST['LogIn'])) {
    $UN = $_POST['userName'];
    $PW = $_POST['password'];
    //write sql to check for email or username
    $query = "SELECT * from user where Username=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $UN);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
    if($row && password_verify($PW, $row['Password'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];
        header( 'Location: Account.php' );
        die;
    }

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['LogInFail'] = "Yes";
}
```